# How to see published messages in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

i am new to kafka.How we can see the published messages under a kafka topics(i am using confluent kafka images)?
I checked the confluent rest api documentation. I didn't find anything. Is it mandatory to create consumer for that topic to see messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to create consumer for that topic to see messages?

Yes. https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

---

The Confluent REST Proxy (if that is what you are referring to) acts as a consumer itself.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html  in this api documentation covering all the information regarding creating a consumer.

Comment: Only if you are using the REST proxy, which is not provided by Apache Kafka, then, yes that's the correct page. That's not the only way to consume messages, though